# How to share data between an activity and a fragment using a SharedViewModel?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-viewmodel, android-architecture-navigation

I have an activity class where I have added a fragment using Navigation Components. I have added an `OnAuthStateChangeListener` in my activity to see when the user is sign-out or not. I have implemented the method like so:

```
override fun onAuthStateChanged(isUserSignedOut: Boolean) {
    if (!isUserSignedOut) {
        sharedViewModel.setUid(uid)
    }
}
```

My `SharedViewModel` class looks like so:

```
class SharedViewModel @Inject constructor(): ViewModel() {
    val liveData = MutableLiveData<String>()

    fun setUid(uid: String) {
        liveData.value = uid
    }
}
```

Now in my fragment, I tried to get the uid like so:

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    sharedViewModel.liveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer<String> { uid ->
        logErrorMessage("uid: $uid")
    })
}
```

But that observer never fires. I have no output in the logcat whatsoever. How can I get that uid correctly?

Comment: does `onAuthStateChanged` gets called before `sharedViewModel.liveData.observe`?

Comment: @FranzAndel I have added a log statement before `sharedViewModel.liveData.observe` and the order is: first is the "before" log statement and right after that is the `onAuthStateChanged` called. Is it bad?

Comment: No, it is already correct. The basic idea is observe first then emit. Can you make sure that `sharedViewModel` has the same instance in both `activity` and `fragment`?

Comment: @FranzAndel Yes, it's the same instance, since it is injected in both activity and fragment.

Comment: well, i think you should debug in `sharedViewModel.setUid(uid)` line, make sure it is hit.

Comment: @FranzAndel It is hit, because I put a log statement inside `fun setUid(uid)` and it is triggered. Do you have any other idea? Thanks anyway

Comment: does that fragment destroyed before `sharedViewModel.setUid(uid)` being called?

Comment: @FranzAndel No, both are active. Is there any problem that i call `sharedViewModel.liveData.observe` inside `onActivityCreated`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219447/discussion-between-franz-andel-and-ivan-patrice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a long discussion,

This happens because the instance of `sharedViewModel` in both Activity and Fragment are different.

You need to add `@Singleton` annotation to the way you provide it with Dagger, like this

```
@Module
abstract class AppViewModelModule {
@Singleton
@Binds
abstract fun bindAppViewModelFactory(factory: AppViewModelFactory?): ViewModelProvider.Factory?

@Singleton
@Binds
@IntoMap
@ViewModelKey(SharedViewModel::class)
abstract fun provideSharedViewModel(viewModel: SharedViewModel?): ViewModel?
}
```

Also, add `@Singleton` annotation to `SharedViewModel` class too, like this

```
@Singleton
class SharedViewModel @Inject constructor(): ViewModel() {
    val liveData = MutableLiveData<String>()

    fun setUid(uid: String) {
        liveData.value = uid
    }
}
```

Glad this helped you :)